# Creating a named scope that includes an associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

The model `Organizer` `has_many` `events`.

`Event` has attributes `begin_day:date` and `published:boolean`.

I have the following query for events that haven't ocurred yet:

```
@organizer.events.order('begin_day asc').where('begin_day >= ?', Date.today).where(published: true).limit(8)
```

which I would like to extraxt to a scope such that it's implemented something like this:

```
@organizer.upcoming_events.limit(8)
```

**How do I do create this scope though that includes an associated model?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading @TheChamp's reasoning in his answer, it seems like just doing a method pasting in the query part works equally well. Chainable as well.

```
class Event
  belongs_to :organizer
end

class Organizer
  has_many :events

  def upcoming_events
    self.events.order('begin_day asc').where('begin_day >= ?', Date.today).where(published: true)
  end       

  end
end
```

This works now:

```
@organizer.upcoming_events.limit(8)
```

Comment: looks good to me, and it uses the `events` scope much nicer :)

Answer (score 1):

Try smth like this:

```
scope :upcoming_events, -> { joins(:events).where("events.begin_day >= ?", Date.today).where(events: {published: true}).order('events.begin_day asc') }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `has_many` and `belongs_to` helpers automatically create fields and scopes that easily allow you to join two models, in a user defined scope you have to join those models manually. ;)

```
class Event
  belongs_to :organizer
end

class Organizer
  has_many :events

  scope :upcoming_events, joins(:events).order('begin_day asc').where('begin_day >= ?', Date.today).where(published: true)

  # lol007's query
  scope :upcoming_events, -> { joins(:events).where("events.begin_day >= ?", Date.today).where(events: {published: true}).order('events.begin_day asc') }

  end
end
```

Comment: It may raise error, for example, `PG::Error: ERROR:  column reference "published" is ambiguous` if `published` column is present at both models

Comment: your query is definitely safer

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, look at my answer. Is there any benefit going with `scope` in this case?